# Pull down view controller from top to bottom like Facebook paper iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook

Could you please give me some idea how to pull down a view controller from top to bottom like Facebook paper app.In paper app when a view pull from top to bottom the setting screen will come.

I have searched didn't get any idea. No need for code, any idea........

Comment: Ok, here's one: check out any open source sliding menu project and do the same, but with different orientation and probably sizes.

Comment: @A-Live So I will go with sliding menu with top to bottom animation instead of right to left....

Comment: Yep, exactly what you want as far as I understand.

Comment: Take a look at [this project](https://github.com/matej/MBPullDownController)

Comment: Thanks Mendyk, I have already gone through this project. The top view controller must be scrollview according to the project.But I got some idea.